# Mean and variance of a combination of uniform and standard normal random variables.

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables. Suppose that $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$. Find the expectation (mean) and variance of $H=Ye^{XY}$.

I have tried to show that the random variables $H$ and $Y$ are independent, which I believe would facilitate the proof. Am I in the right track? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods you can use to solve the question

1. You can start with using the definition of expectation

$$\mathbb{E}[Ye^{XY}]=\int_0^{1}\Bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y e^{xy}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy\Bigg]dx=$$

$$=\int_0^{1}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\Bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}dy\Bigg]dx=\int_0^1 x e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\sqrt{e}-1$$

The integral in the $[...]$ braces is $=x$ because it is the expectation of a normal rv $N(x,1)$

---

2. Using conditional properties

$$\mathbb{E}[Ye^{XY}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Ye^{XY}|Y]]=\mathbb{E}[Y\mathbb{E}[e^{XY}|Y]]=\mathbb{E}[e^Y-1])=\sqrt{e}-1$$

and this because

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{XY}|Y=y]=\int_0^1 e^{xy}dx=\frac{e^y}{y}-\frac{1}{y}$$

and going on solving,

$$\mathbb{E}[e^Y-1]=\mathbb{E}[e^Y]-1=\sqrt{e}-1$$

because $e^Y\sim$ [lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

---

To calculate the variance calculate first second simple moment with the same procedure than you can get the variance remembering that

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$

Comment: Very nice answer. I see that you modified the expectation definition taking into account the exponential function. I missed that result!

Comment: @matumath : I did not modify anything. The definition of expectationis the following $E[g(X,Y)]=\int \int g(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy$